# Is there a better way to implement arrays in python

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array

So here is my approach:

```
def transpose(m):
    output = [["null" for i in range(len(m))] for j in range(len(m[0]))]
    for i in range(len(m[0])):
        for j in range(len(m)):
            if i==j:
                output[i][j]=m[i][j]
            else:
                output[i][j]=m[j][i]
    return(output)
```

the above method creates an array/list as a placeholder so that new values can be added. I tried this approach because I am new to python and was previously learning Java which had built-in arrays but python doesn't and I found there was no easy way of indexing 2D lists similar to what we do in java unless we predefine list (like in java but had to use some `for` loops). I know there are packages which implement arrays but I am fairly new to the language so I tried simulating it the way I was familiar.

So my main question is that is there a better approach to predefine lists for a restricted *kinda* size (like arrays in java) without these funky `for` loops. OR even a better way to have predefined list which I can then easily index without needing to append list inside list and all those stuff. Its really difficult for me because it doesn't behave like I want.

Also I made a helper method for prebuilding lists like this:

```
def arraybuilder(r,c,jagged=[]): #builds an empty placeholder 2D array/list of required size
    output=[]
    if not jagged:
       output = [["null" for i in range(c)] for j in range(r)]
       return(output)
    else:
        noOfColumns=[]
        for i in range(len(jagged)):
            noOfColumns.append(len(jagged[i]))
        for i in range(len(jagged)):
            row=[]
            for j in range(noOfColumns[i]):
                row.append("null")
            output.append(row)
        return(output,noOfColumns)#returns noOfColumns as well for iteration purposes
```

Comment: I don't mean to single you out, but I correct indentation like this on a daily basis. Why is it so hard to get the first line of a code snippet right when posting code?

Comment: Feast your eyes on https://numpy.org/

Comment: You have rows and columns backwards in your `arraybuilder()` function.

Comment: `[[None] * c for _ in r]`

Comment: @Barmar i will fix it just a sec

Answer (score 1):

The typical transposition pattern for 2d iterables is `zip(*...)`:

```
def transpose(m):
    return [*map(list, zip(*m))]
    # same as:
    # return [list(col) for col in zip(*m))]
```

`zip(*m)` unpacks the nested lists and zips (interleaves) them into column tuples. Since `zip` returns a lazy iterator over tuples, we consume it into a list while converting all the tuples into lists as well.

And if you want to be more explicit, there are more concise ways of creating a nested list. Here is a nested comprehension:

```
def transpose(m):
    return [[row[c] for row in m] for c in range(len(m[0]))]
```

Comment: First one also has the benefit of not crashing for empty matrices.